# Is it possible to force the use of the MRTK's InputSimulationService in a build?

Tags: mrtk

I'm working on a multiplayer application based on the MixedRealityToolkit v2. In order to test the network system, I need to make several builds to launch the clients and the server, and I would like to do this on the same machine without having to use the real device (or an emulator). The problem is that the Input Simulation Service works only in the Unity Editor, which means I can't test more than one client on the same machine; moreover, to use the real device (HoloLens or Windows Mixed Reality Headset) I have to build a UWP app, which is a much slower process than building for WindowsStandalone.

Is there a way to force the MRTKv2 to use the Input Simulation Service in a build (possibly a WindowsStandalone build)?

Thank you in advance to anyone will try to help me!

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the feedback

This is being resolved in MRTK with the following PR https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/pull/7018

Comment: This post isn't an actual attempt at answering the question. Please note [StackOverflow doesn't work like a discussion forum](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), it is a Q&A site where every post is either a question or an answer to a question. Posts can also have [comments](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) - small sentences like this one - that can be used to critique or request clarification from an author. This should be either a comment or a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Answer (score 0):

The input simulation was intended for the editor primarily, using it outside the editor is not currently supported.

That being said i can see the value of using it in standalone as you describe. I've made a quick attempt at enabling the service on all platforms, which isn't too difficult (see below).

The main showstopper is that articulated hand poses are loaded from JSON files, which are searched using the [MixedRealityToolkitFiles](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/blob/mrtk_development/Assets/MixedRealityToolkit/Utilities/Editor/Setup/MixedRealityToolkitFiles.cs) utility, which only works in editor builds. Without this the data for animating the simulated hands is missing.

For completeness i'm listing the steps i tried below. Perhaps you can come up with a platform-independent solution for loading those files.

- Edit

  `Assets\MixedRealityToolkit.Services\InputSimulation\MixedRealityToolkit.Services.InputSimulation.asmdef`

  Remove *all* entries in `"includePlatforms"`. This will include the input simulation assembly in all builds.

  - Move `Assets\MixedRealityToolkit.Services\InputSimulation\Editor\InputSimulationService.cs` down one level into `Assets\MixedRealityToolkit.Services\InputSimulation\` (The `Editor` assembly needs UnityEditor specific code).
  - This will probably break the service entry in the profile. Select MixedRealityToolkit object and go to *Input > Input Data Providers > Input Simulation Service* in the inspector. Then hit the "Try repair" button or select the correct service type manually.
  - Set the Platforms for input simulation to "Everything" to actually enable the service on all platforms. [image]

At this point the input simulation will still work in the editor, but when you try to build it there will be an error that the `LoadGesturePoses` function can not be found. This function is in `Assets/MixedRealityToolkit/Definitions/Utilities/ArticulatedHandPose.cs`. Notice the `#if UNITY_EDITOR` section. Removing the #if will complain about not finding the MixedRealityToolkitFiles class, which is also in an editor assembly.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed instructions.

I will work on your solution for simulating the HoloLens-like input system outside the editor; if I will get it to work, I will post a working project here.

In the meantime, I have also worked on a custom VR Input Simulation Service which works both in the editor and in a Win32 build as well; I will post the link to the GitHub repo in case anyone is interested in using it.

Answer (score 0):

I have created an alternative Input Simulation Service for the MixedRealityToolkit which tries to emulate a VR system. This service works both in the editor and in a Win32 build.

Since this is a very fast work it is not bug-free, but should work for testing purposes.

https://github.com/DamianoOriti/MRTK-Custom-Input-Simulation-Service